# Jenkins MSbuild plugin not working

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I have configured MSBuild plugin in Jenkins using Global tool configuration section.

Detailed information which I have provided is -

```
Name : MSBuild.exe
Path to MSBuild : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
Default parameters : **No parameters**
```

In the job configuration page the infiormation regarding MSBuild looks like -

```
MSBuild Version : (Default)
MSBuild Build File  : WSCSharp.sln
Command line arguments : **None**
Pass build variables as properties : **Unchecked**
Continue Job on build Failure :  **Unchecked**
If warnings set the build to Unstable : **Unchecked**
```

The project is a simple C# application which can be run by using command -

```
msbuild WSCSharp.sln /t:Build
```

But, now when I run the program, it throws error while building in Jenkins--

```
Building on master in workspace D:\Programs\Jenkins\jobs\WSCsharp\workspace
Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C " msbuild.exe WSCSharp.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from D:\Programs\Jenkins\jobs\WSCsharp\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C " msbuild.exe WSCSharp.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
'msbuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So basically it is running the command : `msbuild.exe WSCSharp.sln` internally. Any idea why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have tried to edit the path to MSBuild like this :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
```

This didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same problem.

The solution for me was to include the 'MSBuild.exe' in the path and this fixed the problem for me.

```
Path to MSBuild : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
```

Edit:

Change the 'MSBuild Version' to 'MSBuild.exe' instead of '(Default)'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is not working either.

Comment: Have you tried to set the 'MSBuild Version' to 'MSBuild.exe' instead of '(Default)'?

Comment: Ah ok.. Now it is recognizing the command msbuid.exe. Thanks.. can you please edit the answer so that I can accept this as an answer? Thanks a lot!